# Is there something wrong with the partition I created with gparted?

Tags: partitioning

I used gparted to install a new partition, but the partition seems useless.  I can see the partition in Disk Management, but it has no properties--it's empty.  I tried installing ubuntu on it--and I thought I succeeded--but the partition was empty after ubuntu stopped installing.  Disk Management shows the partition has 60.29 GBs available and 100% free space, but it also shows nothing listed under volume or file system.   What is wrong with my partition?  Thanks

Comment: This is the link to a snap shot of my partitions http://imgur.com/DSZZfuw

Comment: Windows cannot understand the ext4 formatted partitions used by Ubuntu. Please boot Ubuntu live DVD/USB and upload gparted screen shot.

Comment: I am so new.  Not sure what you are asking.  I booted to Ubuntu from USB--am there now.  I have no gparted app that I know of.  When I search for it, I get what looks live a volume.  When I click on it, there a couple thousand little pics in it.  However, when I right click on the volume I created, I get what looks like what I expect: 3.6 GB used, 56.8 GB of free space, file system type is ext3/ext4.  Here is a link to a snap shot http://imgur.com/jSvLHBn

Comment: It looks like you have installed Ubuntu in that partition. When you boot the computer without the Live USB, it should let you choose between Windows and Ubuntu. There is nothing wrong with the partition.

Comment: This partition is not recognized in the BIOS.  I have no option to boot to Ubuntu.  This is what is confusing me.

Comment: While you are in Live version of Ubuntu, click on Dash (the top icon on the left panel) and type **gparted** in the search box. Click on gparted to start it. It should open a screen much like the one in your question. capture that screen and post the link to the uploaded image as before.

Comment: This is a link to the snap shot of gparted http://imgur.com/bocg4T0

Comment: I tried to do what Fabby suggested, but I don't know what to put in for X and Y.  An aside, the system here at askubuntu.com is asking if I would like to move this discussion to chat.  I am new here and to forums in general.  Should I move our discourse to chat?  I don't want to lose this information you have been kind enough to provide.

Comment: I figured out X and Y. It is sda.  Anyway, here is a link to what terminal said http://imgur.com/K1Z7OQd.  I will now try the fix recommended at bottom of terminal page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're showing is the windows disk manager which doesn't recognize EXT3/EXT4 partitions.  If you did install Ubuntu (and [it looks like it from your screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUYUw.jpg)), just reboot from your hard disk and you should see a menu showing you how to boot into Windows or how to boot into Ubuntu.

1. **If you don't see such a menu,** boot from the USB again, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

   ```
   sudo mount /dev/XdY /mnt
   ```

   Where X is the disk type and Y the disk letter. (probably it's going to be `sda` but if you're unsure, leave a comment)
2. Then, bind the directories that the Ubuntu boot loader (`grub`: **GR**and **U**nifying **B**ootloader) needs access to to detect other operating systems:

   ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev &&
   sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts &&
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc &&
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
   ```
3. Then change the directory and make it root (`chroot`), install `grub` and

   ```
   sudo chroot /mnt
   grub-install /dev/XdY
   grub-install --recheck /dev/XdY
   update-grub
   ```

and reboot and you should be able to boot into Ubuntu without the USB stick.

[<sub>Source</sub>](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually using Windows cmd to try & run linux commands? And Windows disk management to see what's going on?

That's not (ever) going to work - Windows is deliberately blind to other OS's, to discourage you from tinkering, and does not have the tools to do this. So the answer to your question is perhaps that there's nothing wrong at all...

If you can get it to boot the linux OS, you should find it *has* worked.

Comment: The BIOS does not recognize the partition.  But when I boot into ubuntu from the USB, I see the partition, and it looks good.  See the links above for snap shots of this.  No, I am not using Windows command to run linux; I was doing what was suggested above to obtain certain information from the command.

Answer (score 0):

It's extremely likely that nothing is wrong with the partition that you created with gparted. What's wrong is expecting Windows to recognize native file systems of Non-Microsoft operating systems. Boot the system, choose Ubuntu from the GRUB menu and you'll find that Ubuntu happily recognizes all your file systems (including Microsoft’s). If you have installed Ubuntu this should work famously, If not, boot from the installation media and install on the unused partition.